How to remove the DUAL BIOS logo from the GA-G31M-ES2L boot screen?
I'm sure it's a niche / obscure question, but worth a try. I have a Gigabyte G31M-ES2L motherboard with Award BIOS. I'm aware that using some tool it's possible to change the EPA logo in the top right. But I'm more interested in removing the "DUAL BIOS" logo that's just below the EPA logo. See here:

Anyone has any idea how to do that? Would greatly appreciate any help

Have you studied the manual?

@ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yep, but I did not see anything to indicate that that logo can be removed. Maybe, due to my limited technical knowledge, I missed something. But as far as I saw, nothing to indicate removal of dual bios logo

Is LGA 775 (Intel Core2) already retro?

@Raffzahn arguably not, but I don’t think that’s the significant part of this question — the main constraint is the BIOS. Award BIOS 6 was initially released in 1998; obviously it had lots of updates after that, but the core aspects of this Q&A haven’t changed since then. There are plenty of existing articles on this topic, but most if not all of them point to tools which are no longer available except on Internet Archive, so this is useful if only for providing a consistent set of instructions and downloadable tools (which doesn’t matter in an on-topicness discussion, I know).

@StephenKitt No prob. I have no intention to down vote. Beside that PCs are becoming more retro over time, it's a rather obscure and thus interesting topic. And you provided a great answer.  Still, being from 1998 doesn't nullify the point that those BIOS logos are still there today , AFAICT (given, my last PC build is already 5 yo)

@Raffzahn right, but system firmware updates have changed since then, what with UEFI and all that ;-).

I mean, there's some possibility someone would ask why they're running such an old platform on super user, and most modern machines do UEFI. Personally I wouldn't consider a C2D retro, and the idea of that makes me feel very very old :D

@JourneymanGeek Oh no, the motherboard itself isn't retro at all. The reason I put this in retro SE is because I'm using it to run Windows 98 SE, which I guess is semi-retro? And that Award BIOS screen (minus the Dual Boot thing) is something I remember from childhood and wanted to replicate it the best I can. Hence wanted to remove the Dual Boot logo. I hope that clarifies for both you and Raffzahn why I put it in retro SE, even though the hardware isn't all that old

I haven’t tried this with your motherboard, your mileage may vary. (Since your board has dual BIOS support you should be able to recover from mishaps, but it’s up to you to decide what level of risk you’re comfortable with.)
Logos are usually identifiable as separate resources in Award BIOS images. Starting with the appropriate BIOS download for your motherboard (check the revision; I’m using BIOS FC since that’s what you’re currently using, but you might want to use a later version):

Extract the image from the download:
7z x mb_bios_ga-g31m-es2l_2.x_fc.exe G31MES2L.FC

(or run the file, it will auto-extract).

Examine the image using CBROM:
cbrom G31MES2L.FC /D

This shows the usual EPA logo, and an additional “LOGO1 ROM”.

Extract the additional logo:
cbrom G31MES2L.FC /logo1 extract

This will ask for a file name, defaulting to dbios.bmp which sounds promising. Rename the file to dbios.epa (because it’s an “EPA” image).

Convert the file to a regular BMP with EPACoder: “Open EPA”, then “BMP ← EPA”, and “Save BMP”.

Edit the BMP as you wish. (If you don’t want anything displayed, make it all black.)

Convert it back to EPA using EPACoder again.

Add it to the ROM image:
cbrom G31MES2L.FC /logo1 dbios.epa



This will produce an image with the replacement logo of your choice, ready to flash to your motherboard, using the built-in Q-Flash tool.

Going to be very interesting to hear how it goes!

Hi Stephen! Thanks a ton for the detailed answer. I'll try it and update. Just one question: what version of CBROM should I be using? For EPACoder it seems I should use v1.5, as per your link. What about CBROM?

And a second question - I'm new to flashing but am very comfortable with tech in general. Could you also edit your answer to include how I should flash the ROM image to the motherboard? As in what's the process and what tool+version I should use for that?

@user9343456 I used the latest CBROM version available on IA. To flash the ROM, see the Gigabyte Q-Flash guide.

@StephenKitt : I finally had the chance to give this a go, so here's an update. When I list the stuff present in the BIOS using /D, it gives me a list of 16 items, out of which the 14th one is LOGO1 ROM. I extracted the EPA, converted to BMP and made the BMP all black. When opening the edited BMP in EPACoder again, it gives a warning that the BMP is not of expected size. Even if I convert the original EPA to BMP, and then open the unedited BMP in EPACoder, it gave the same warning. So I ignored it - I made sure that the all black BMP was the correct size and dimensions (cont'd...)

(cont'd)... Then I added the new EPA (converted from the edited BMP) to the ROM file. When I relisted using /D for the edited ROM image, now the LOGO1 ROM was listed at the 16th position instead of the 14th as in the original ROM image. I ignored it and flashed using the @BIOS tool by Gigabyte. The operation completed successfully, but upon restarting, I got the BIOS checksum fatal error, and the BIOS thankfully got autorecovered from the backup BIOS. I'm not sure where exactly the problem occurred, but would be grateful for any tips or troubleshooting steps you may know

@StephenKitt : It worked! Basically I was using atBIOS or DOS flash utility so far. But when I used Qflash, it worked flawlessly. That dreaded is dual bios logo is gone! Thanks so much

@StephenKitt : Another follow-up question if at all possible - that long "Main Processor" line eats into the logo. Is there any way to remove or modify that line, to the best of your knowledge? If needed, I can frame this as a separate new question...

@user9343456 I’m not aware of a way to change that line, other than modifying the BIOS code itself. You could ask a new question, perhaps someone else would have a better idea!
